# Move data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How do I retrieve data from one MySQL table and store the data into another database table on the same server. I have tried this code but keep getting errors:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ProfusionTest` () 
LANGUAGE SQL 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 

DELETE FROM `Profusion`.`source_cdr`; 

INSERT INTO 
    `dest_table`.`create_info` 
    SELECT * FROM `Profusion`.`source_cdr`; 

END
```

Comment: put delete after insert

Answer (score 1):

In same server you just need to use alter table to do that.

```mysql
ALTER TABLE `old_db.foo` RENAME `new_db.foo`;
```